# How to insert html like tag "<s></s>" for a string using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with a text corpus, where there are three sentences. I want to insert html like tag `<s>` at the start and `</s>` at the end of each sentence using regular expression. Below the partial code is given:

```
text = '''
       I live in SOME_PLACE.
       I am a graduate student.
       My school is in SOME_PLACE.
       '''
```

and what I want is a python string formatted as,

```
text_new = '<s> I live in SOME_PLACE. </s> <s> I am a graduate student. </s> <s> My school is in SOME_PLACE. </s>'
```

i.e. I want the sentence boundaries to be mentioned. Please give some valuable suggestions.

Comment: why a regex? `'<s>' + replace('\n', '</s><s>', text) + '</s>'` would work just as well.

Comment: @MarcB: `replace()`? Do you mean `text.replace('\n', '</s><s>')`?

Comment: probably. never done python before, so whatever it uses for basic string search/replace.

Comment: It's showing `NameError: name 'replace' is not defined`

Comment: @Koushik KevinGuan is right.  You should use `text.replace`, not `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
text = '''
       I live in SOME_PLACE.
       I am a graduate student.
       My school is in SOME_PLACE.
       '''

text_new = ' '.join('<s> {} </s>'.format(l.strip()) for l in text.splitlines() if len(l.strip()))
print text_new
```

Or as a regular expression:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'^\s+(.*)\n', r'<s> \1 </s> ', text, flags=re.M)
```

This displays the following:

```
<s> I live in SOME_PLACE. </s> <s> I am a graduate student. </s> <s> My school is in SOME_PLACE. </s>
```